# Is it better to create seprate tables for Current employees and employees which are going to join in future?

Tags: database

We are creating an application for managing the employees in the company for the HR. So we will have a employee table for this.

Now HR may also forecast that ten new employees are going to join ourr company in next months say if today is April, then we will have 10 new employee in may.

They may also forecast for later months as well say August and december. This is very hypothetically because till tghey actually joing we may or may not employees exact details like name etc.

It can also happen that forecast is wrong and instead of ten now only 5 are joining.

For every forecast HR will go and add record in employee table with some placeholders for name etc as it may be unknown.

Same applies for firing, e.g. Company needs to downsize and HR is asked to fire say 10 employees in April (details again unknown but they will go and add 5 employees leavers).

So is it better idea to have them in seprate tables (live employees and future leavers and joiners) and once the actual activity takes place put them in the live employee tables?

But the operations like reporting etc is going to take place on both tables as if they were single table.

In all reports I will not be differentiating them as current or future employees.

So, for eg if someone asks what will employee count at end of april , it will current + future 10.

As well we need to audit employee table and forecast table also so functionality wise ther is no difference between current employee and forecst employees.

Or is it better to keep flag in employee table to indicate its a forecast.

Please help.

Comment: Keep it in one table and just add a flag to the employees. The flag keeps it sortable. Also, anyone performing operations on this table doesn't necessarily have to know that there are two separate groups. If there were two separate tables, everyone who ever did anything to one table would have to remember to do it to the other table... Keep it simple!

Answer (score 3):

No.  Keep them in the same table.  Differentiate the hires from the fires using a `status` column.

When you do your reporting, you can filter the report to process only the records you want by using a WHERE clause in your SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can add a status field which will indicate if its a new joiner or leaver. But what about the current employees. What will they have in the status column? Because on day one when the application is deployed we will already have 500 existing employees which needs to be inserted in the employee table. These are not new joiners or leavers.

Comment: You can have more than two possible statuses.

Comment: There will be ceratin fields like status, status 2, status 3, joiningOrLeavging date etc relevant to forecast only. Shall I keep them in seperate table? Off Course existing employees can also leave so they may also have these fileds but not at the begining.

Comment: No.  You have one status field with three or more possible values (make it a numeric field).  All employees, regardless of status, go into the same table.

Answer (score -1):

I would keep them in separate tables and combine the data to get the answers you need rather than combine tables and have lots of placeholders.

Comment: But then lets say my employee table has few other relation tables like employee_products etc. I will need to have same tables for forecast also. Plus the tasof of doing audits etc have to be done on two sets of tables now.